# How do you count the number of rows in a table that have the same value in value in a column?

Tags: sql, select, count

Suppose I have the following simple table:

```
create table mytable (
    desid bigint not null,
    ancid bigint not null
  );

insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (1,10);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (1,20);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (1,21);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (1,22);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (2,30);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (3,40);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (3,41);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (3,42);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (3,43);
```

What is the SQL command that will print out the following information:

```
4 rows with ancid=1
1 rows with ancid=2
4 rows with ancid=3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the information by grouping by the `ancid`:

```sql
SELECT   ancid, COUNT(*)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY ancid
```