# How do I modify an sql query to display additional information only if the number of occurences is greater than 3?

Tags: sql

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65782256/how-do-you-count-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table-that-have-the-same-value-in-value) the solution shows how to count the number of occurrences of desid for each unique ancid.  How do you modify the solution to the question so that it gives extra information about counts bigger than 3?

For example, if I have a table structure like:

```
create table mytable (
    desid bigint not null,
    ancid bigint not null
  );

insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (1,10);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (1,20);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (1,21);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (1,22);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (2,30);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (3,40);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (3,41);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (3,42);
insert into mytable (ancid,desid) values (3,43);

create table desinfo (
        desid bigint not null,
        age bigint not null,
        size bigint not null
      );
  
insert into desinfo (desid, age, size) (10, 22, 100); 
insert into desinfo (desid, age, size) (20, 23, 101); 
insert into desinfo (desid, age, size) (21, 24, 102); 
insert into desinfo (desid, age, size) (22, 25, 103); 
insert into desinfo (desid, age, size) (30, 26, 104); 
insert into desinfo (desid, age, size) (40, 27, 105); 
insert into desinfo (desid, age, size) (41, 28, 106); 
insert into desinfo (desid, age, size) (42, 29, 107); 
insert into desinfo (desid, age, size) (43, 30, 108);
```

From the solution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65782256/how-do-you-count-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table-that-have-the-same-value-in-value) , we can run the following query:

```
SELECT   ancid, COUNT(*)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY ancid
```

which gives me an output like:

```
4 rows with ancid=1
1 rows with ancid=2
4 rows with ancid=3
```

How do I modify the query to get additional information about desid counts > 3.  For example, the 4 desids with ancsid=1 and ancsid=3 I would like the "age" and "size" properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the analytical function `count` as follows:

```
select * from
(SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) over (partition by ancid) as cnt
   FROM mytable t ) t
where cnt > 3
```

Comment: I think what I was looking for is this: select * from desinfo where desid in (select desid from
(SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) over (partition by ancid) as cnt
   FROM mytable t ) t
where cnt > 3)     but I will give you credit since you are very close.